# How to fix output from repeating cout from IF/ELSE statments

Tags: c++

I have a completed code for my class; it creates a randomized string based on how many characters that the user asks for, and it then allows for the user to specify if they want to find a particular pair of characters in the string. That last part is based on a `if`/`else` statement that either gives the location, or is suppose to tell them there is no pair in the string.

My issue is that, when given a pair to find, if its in the string it gives the corrected statement, however, it also gives the `else` statement, repeated several times. if the pair is not in the string, it then gives the correct `else` statement, but repeats the `cout` several times. I don't know how to solve this issue.

Here is my code and screen shots of my outputs.

[image]

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int i=0, n;
    char alphabet[26];
    char RandomStringArray [100];
    char Ltr1, Ltr2;
    srand(time(0));

    cout <<"How many letters do you want in your random string (no less than 0, no more than 100): ";
    cin >> n;

    for (int i=0; i<=25; i++)
            alphabet[i] = 'a' + i;

    while(i<n) {
        int temp = rand() % 26;
        RandomStringArray[i] = alphabet[temp];
        i++;
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout<<RandomStringArray[i];
    cout<<"\n";

    cout<<"What letter pair would you like to find? ";
    cin>>Ltr1>>Ltr2;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        if (Ltr1==RandomStringArray[i] && Ltr2== RandomStringArray[i+1]){
            cout<<"The pair is in the string starting at character number "<<i+1<<" in the string. \n";
        }
        else if (Ltr1!=RandomStringArray[i] && Ltr2!= RandomStringArray[i+1])
            cout<<"no";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using for loop which means that if and else if statement will be executed as many times as value `n` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final `for` loop is looping through every character in the random string from begin to end, which is fine for searching, but it is outputting the result of comparing *every* character, which is not what you want.  Don't display any output at all until the loop is finished, eg:

```
for (i = 0; i < (n-1); i++)
{
    if (RandomStringArray[i] == Ltr1 && RandomStringArray[i+1] == Ltr2)
        break;
}

if (i < (n-1))
    cout << "The pair is in the string starting at character number " << i+1 << " in the string.\n";
else
    cout << "The pair is not found in the string.\n";
```

I would suggest wrapping the search in a function, eg:

```
int findPair(const char *str, int len, char Letter1, char Letter2)
{
    for (i = 0; i < (len-1); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == Letter1 && str[i+1] == Letter2)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

...

i = findPair(RandomStringArray, n, Ltr1, Ltr2);
if (i != -1)
    cout << "The pair is in the string starting at character number " << i+1 << " in the string.\n";
else
    cout << "The pair is not found in the string.\n";
```

That being said, since you are using C++ anyway, you should go full C++, not a mix of C and C++, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    int n;
    char alphabet[26];
    std::string RandomString;
    char LtrPair[2];

    std::generate(std:begin(alphabet), std::end(alphabet), [ch = 'a'] () mutable { return ch++; } );

    std::cout << "How many letters do you want in your random string: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 25);

    RandomString.resize(n);
    std::generate(RandomString.begin(), RandomString.end(), [&](){ return alphabet[dis(gen)]; };

    std::cout << RandomString << "\n";

    std::cout << "What letter pair would you like to find? ";
    cin >> LtrPair[0] >> LtrPair[1];

    auto pos = RandomString.find(LtrPair, 0, 2);
    if (pos != std::string::npos)
        std::cout << "The pair is in the string starting at character number " << pos+1 << " in the string.\n";
    else
        std::cout << "The pair is not found in the string.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I feel stupid at this point, I never thought of using a `break;` to stop that issue from occurring. Thanks for the help! I would use your second method, but I am taking an intro course into C++, I don't want to get too ahead of the program right now, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have placed your `if...else` construct inside of a `for` loop, it is evaluated every time.  This means that for every instance where the first condition isn't true, the `else` clause is executed, causing your "no" message to repeat.

Comment: I am still new to C++, or even coding in general, where should I place the `if...else` for all this to still work?

Comment: @Zethos The problem is not the `if`/`else` itself, since obviously you need to make comparisons and decisions based on the string content.  The problem is what you are doing inside of the `if`/`else` - you are always outputting something to the console on *every* loop iteration, which is not what you want. You want to output only the *final result* of the loop, not what the loop does while it is running.